# How come I cannot get this .EXE to work with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, console, pyinstaller, exe

I am trying to just play around with Pycharm and Pyinstaller as I am very new to python and am trying to create a .exe file that simply displays a chunk of parented html from a website, just to test. I got it to work within Pycharm but when I run it as an exe, it just opens and closes a blank console. I created the exe using:

`pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed main.py`

(main is the file name).

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

Url = "https://www.premierleague.com/players/5178/Mohamed-Salah/stats"
DisplayText = ""

Request = requests.get(Url)
Htmlcode = BeautifulSoup(Request.text, "html.parser")
search = Htmlcode.findAll(text="Goals   ")
narrow = search[0].parent

input(narrow)
```

also I think, but I am not sure, windows security may be screwing with this but I am not sure.

Comment: The windowed flag is pointless here; it's designed for apps that have a GUI frontend (Tk wx, Qt, etc) Once building without the flag, run the executable generated from the command line. What error does it print?

Answer (score 1):

Try running as pyinstaller instead of pyinstaller.exe, and unless it's a typo check the last line of code, ''' after the input(narrow) would cause an error

EDIT:
run as

```
pyinstaller --onefile yourFile.py
```

without the --windowed, there's no need for the --windowed tag and that's what's causing the error

Comment: I tried what you recommended and got this as an error:       Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception: input(): lost sys.stdin.                                                       
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin

Comment: I also got this error in the terminal before running anything: File C:\Users\caile\PycharmProjects\WebScrapingtest1\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Users\caile\PycharmProjects\WebScrapingtest1\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1 is 
not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.   + CategoryInfo     : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Comment: not sure what I am doing wrong here but from other places I have seen online, this whole process should not be this difficult

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).